Using bevy 3d results in error spam from WGPU-HAL
The exact error message I am getting:
2024-06-10T19:28:29.823391Z ERROR log: wgpu-hal heuristics assumed that the view dimension will be equal to `D2` rather than `D2Array`.
`D2` textures with `depth_or_array_layers == 1` are assumed to have view dimension `D2`
`D2` textures with `depth_or_array_layers > 1` are assumed to have view dimension `D2Array`
`D2` textures with `depth_or_array_layers == 6` are assumed to have view dimension `Cube`
`D2` textures with `depth_or_array_layers > 6 && depth_or_array_layers % 6 == 0` are assumed to have view dimension `CubeArray`  

The code:
It is the rapier 3d example from the site. Though this issue persists with the 3d example from the official bevy site.
Environment:

Archlinux
GNOME wayland (issue persists on XORG)
AMD GPU

Observed behavior:
The example runs just fine apart from my terminal getting bombarded by this error log.
